# Magento 2 Admin not logged in

Tags: magento2, php, admin, admin-login

I've install Latest version of `Magento 2.1.8` and i've try to login into admin and working perfectly but after a few days i'm not be able to login again, i've reset the password, clean cache and i've creating a new user  but the some result.

See this screenshot [image]

So Any Suggestions please about that

Comment: Very common issue. Did you deploy and reindex too? Hope you clear cache manually from /var/cache, /var/page_cache/, /var/generation/, /var/di etc

Comment: Yes, i've deploy and reindex but the some result.

Comment: @Jai also some result.

Comment: Do you have redis or varnish enabled on the server its running?

Comment: @DavaGordon no any redis or varnish running.